# In maven-docker-plugin '~/.m2' cannot be relativized, cannot resolve arbitrary user home paths

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, fabric8, docker-maven-plugin

I have a parent pom written by someone else, it is used for building and running a docker image locally. When I am trying to build using parent pom.xml, I am getting following error `'~/.m2' cannot be relativized, cannot resolve arbitrary user home paths.`
I think the error is with bind volumes to the image. This is how it is defined in parent pom.xml

```
<volumes>
  <bind>
    <volume>${session.executionRootDirectory}:${session.executionRootDirectory}</volume>
    <!-- Mounts the Maven repository so that the Docker container doesn't have to re-download dependencies. -->
    <volume>~/.m2:/root/.m2</volume>
 </bind>
</volumes>
```

The above project is building fine on mac os, and I am using a windows machine. I installed `docker for windows` and read the [fabric8 documentation](http://dmp.fabric8.io/#start-volumes), to know how to bind volumes to your image but could not find any example related to my issue.

Comment: It's using a *NIX path referring to the user's home directory `~`. On Windows that surely won't work, no. You'll have to replace that to the correct path to maven's `.m2` repo directory on your system.

Comment: yeah if I change it to C:\Users\<username>\.m2  this error resolves, but the other volume to be mounted gives ` Mount denied:
The source path "C:/path/to/current/project/directory:C"
doesn't exist and is not known to Docker (Internal Server Error: 500)]` I think it is because the image is built using oracle linux and I the path ${session.executionRootDirectory} resolves to 'C:' so it is giving this error. What should I mention instead of ${session.executionRootDirectory} after ':' in 1st <volume>?

Comment: It should be a *NIX path inside the container, so `/something`.